# Firebase config inside chrome extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I'm doing user authentication inside a chrome extension.
Does including details like

1. apiKey
2. databaseURL
3. messagingSenderId
4. authDomain

Can't create a security leak and expose my users?

Answer (score 0):

**No, they don't risk your users' privacy - these are details that control your connection to Firebase only**. You just have to make sure you control access to your database correctly. You can implement control access with [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data).

For example, you can decide that only users in a whitelist (who've subscribed via your website for example) are allowed to authenticate to the DB to start with (taken from [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#replacesubstring_replacement)):

Allowed emails:

```
{
 "user": {
   "$uid": {
     "email": <email>
   }
 },
 "whitelist": {
   "fred@gmail%2Ecom": true,
   "barney@aol%2Ecom": true
 }
}
```

Allow users from whitelist only:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "root.child('whitelist').child(newData.child('email').val().replace('.', '%2E')).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```